Comparing 3 measurements from same individual to see if they are related?
I am new to statistics and R and looking for some advice. Let's say I'm conducting a study looking at 3 measurements from different parts of the body from the same individual and I want to see if those 3 measurements are related for all of the people in my study. How would I go about doing that? I don't really have a dependent variable unless you count the person but I'm not really sure how that translates to stats? Below is an example of the type of data I have. Any insight is appreciated!
Person 1: 0.44, 0.18, 0.22/
Person 2: 0.34, 0.76, 0.23/
Person 3: 0.54, 0.22, 0.12
etc...

You could do correlations for each pair of measurements.  But it would be amazing if they were not related, so you are just testing how related they are. If you wanted, you could average across the three correlations.

Are you measuring the same physiological parameter at 3 different locations of the same individual, or 3 different physiological parameters at 3 locations of the same individual? This is not clear from the question... For many measurements of the same physilogical parameter, they will obviously be correlated, but there is a lag; time is an element of the relationship (ie some physiological subsystems will lag wrt others; so measuring at the same time will completely miss this. Glucose in different locations being a perfect example of this). Can you clarify?
